# maybe missing a trick with javascript coding - variable handling (socket.io example)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I would finally like to reach some clarity on this aspect of programming, being basically self-taught.  It's to do with passing variables around between functions.

With the code below, data.roomId is not recognized in the first function (obviously). I could place the function inside the joinRoom function to make it recognize data.roomId, but then how does the leaveRoom function recognize sendHeartbeat?

```
`io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    function sendHeartbeat(){
        setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 8000);
        socket.broadcast.to(data.roomId).emit('ping', { beat : 1 });
    }
    socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.roomId)
        setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 8000);
    });
    socket.on('leaveRoom', function (data) {
        socket.leave(data.roomId)
        clearTimeout(sendHeartbeat)
    });
});`
```

Comment: sendHeartbeat is defined within the scope of `function(callback)` - so it is in scope, therefore (as you put it) "recognized"

Answer (score 1):

You can do what we call a closure, it is a function that returns a function keeping track of local variables. It is a cool concept !

```
function sendHeartbeat(roomId){
    return function() {
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('ping', { beat : 1 });
    }
}
socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
    socket.join(data.roomId)
    setTimeout(sendHeartbeat(data.roomId), 8000);
});
```

You call the function sendHeartbeat passing it the roomId, and it returns the function you want to be executed in your setTimeout :)

Comment: Ok, good to know! Guess I'll test it in future but right now I've moved away from pinging to keep a socket.io connection open and went with setting session cookies using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session